# publish_actions extended permissions for posting to Facebook Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I am trying to create an action on an article so when a user, who has authorized the app lands on article, it publishes the fact they've read the article to their timeline.

This works for me without issue but when anyone else tries it, they get an error along the lines of

> Requires extended permission: publish_actions

I saw a notice on Facebook saying :

> While in Open Graph Beta, the 'publish_actions' permission can only be
>   requested from developers and test users of your app. The
>   'publish_actions' permission will be ignored if requested from any
>   other user.

However, the likes of Spotify, Guardian and Independent utilize pretty much exactly what I need. How come? What are they doing differently to me?

Comment: They're partners that tested and launched as part of the announcement at F8 - until the beta ends these are the only apps that can publish custom actions

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok - seems strange that some people are reporting success and others are not.

Comment: I'm almost 100% nobody else has launched since F8 -test users of an app can see and use actions and objects for an app, but they won't be visible to the general public - until timeline launches there won't be any more apps approved to use the (currently beta) open graph APIs

Comment: Ok thanks - after looking around, it seems no one is 100% certain when it will come out of beta. Shame.

Comment: We are seeing the same thing. To clarify, the application owner--the Facebook user that created the application--may log in and post activity. Registered developers and test users may not, contrary to the quoted message from Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit your created action types here: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/opengraph` - once they have been approved you will be able to use them publicly.

Comment: The problem is that that page says you can use them internally with application developers and testers, but it only works for the application creator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit the actions also you need to take the permission from the user.
There are two types of permission, user permission and friends permission. Your suppose to take 'publish_actions' permissions from user as well as from friend.